# Pandas modify column in different way than loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
DF
name1   name2    finalName
AB123   BB123    0
BB113   AB113    0
AB343   AB343    0
CC263   BB263    0
ED633   DD633    0
```

I need to modify `finalName` in that way:
`if name1 starts with AB and name2 starts with BB` - `finalName` should be `BB+number` so in first case: `BB123`.

`if name1 starts with BB and name2 starts with AB` - `finalName` should be `AB+number` so in second case: `AB123`.

In rest of examples `finalName` should stay 0.

I wrote this code:

```
for row in range(len(DF)):
    if(DF.name1.loc[row][0:2] == 'AB' and DF.name2.loc[row][0:2] == 'BB'):
         DF.finalName[row] = DF.name1[row].replace('AB','BB',1)
    if(DF.name1.loc[row][0:2] == 'BB' and DF.name2.loc[row][0:2] == 'AB'):
         DF.finalName[row] = DF.name1[row].replace('BB','AB',1)
```

And I got a `Key error` because I had a missing index (...69,70,72..). So I found info that I need to reindex my df. I done it, and it's work ok. But I also found an info that I shouldn't loop my DF. So my question is:

**How can I do it in pandas way? I mean without loop?**

PS. final df should looks that:

```
DF
name1   name2    finalName
AB123   BB123    BB123   
BB113   AB113    AB113
AB343   AB343    0
CC263   BB263    0
ED633   DD633    0
```

Comment: So necessary replace by another column? Not `DF.finalName[row] = DF.name1[row].replace('AB','BB',1)` but `DF.finalName[row] = DF.name2[row]` ?

Comment: If yes, please change question, because anky and Jaroslav answer replace by `name2`, and my answer by `['BB' + c, 'AB' + c]` where `c` is values of `name1` without 2 letters. Or someting missing?

Comment: @jezrael often is that like u said, but sometimes finalname has different number. So Anky answer is OK for me in that case

Comment: So it means `name1` and `name2` are always same per rows, only different first 2 letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using [`series.str.startswith()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=series+str+starts&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=series+str+starts&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.3452j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
c1=df.name1.str.startswith('AB')&df.name2.str.startswith('BB')
c2=df.name1.str.startswith('BB')&df.name2.str.startswith('AB')
```

---

```
df['finalName']=np.where(c1|c2,df.name2,df.finalName)
print(df)
```

---

```
   name1  name2 finalName
0  AB123  BB123     BB123
1  BB113  AB113     AB113
2  AB343  AB343         0
3  CC263  BB263         0
4  ED633  DD633         0
```

Comment: @jezrael ahh, okay i see what you mean. I assumed the numbers are same in both column Lets wait for OP comment then :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead `replace` is possible add `BB` or `AB` to values of `Series` `c` without first 2 letters with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
a = DF.name1.str[:2] 
b = DF.name2.str[:2] 
c = DF.name1.str[2:] 
m1 = (a == 'AB') & (b == 'BB')
m2 = (a == 'BB') & (b == 'AB')
```

Or:

```
c = DF.name1.str[2:] 
m1 = DF.name1.str.startswith('AB') & DF.name2.str.startswith('BB')
m2 = DF.name1.str.startswith('BB') & DF.name2.str.startswith('AB')
```

---

```
DF['finalName'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['BB' + c, 'AB' + c], DF.finalName)
print (DF)
   name1  name2 finalName
0  AB123  BB123     BB123
1  BB113  AB113     AB113
2  AB343  AB343         0
3  CC263  BB263         0
4  ED633  DD633         0
```

Another solution:

```
DF['finalName'] = np.select([m1, m2], [DF.name1.str.replace('AB','BB',1),
                                       DF.name1.str.replace('BB','AB',1)], DF.finalName)
print (DF)
   name1  name2 finalName
0  AB123  BB123     BB123
1  BB113  AB113     AB113
2  AB343  AB343         0
3  CC263  BB263         0
4  ED633  DD633         0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply()` method like this:

```
def make_finalName(row):
    if row['name1'].startswith('AB') and row['name2'].startswith('BB'):
        return row['name2']
    if row['name1'].startswith('BB') and row['name2'].startswith('AB'):
        return row['name2']
    return row['finalName']

df['finalName'] = df.apply(lambda row: make_finalName(row), axis=1)
```

The output would be following:

```
>> print(df)
   name1  name2 finalName
0  AB123  BB123     BB123
1  BB113  AB113     AB113
2  AB343  AB343         0
3  CC263  BB263         0
4  ED633  DD633         0
```